# ajaxsolr autocomplete suggests only one word

Tags: solr

I have set up ajax solr in local box.
I followed the tutorials from github. I have integrataed the autocomplete feature in my sajax-solr instance.

My auto complete feature suggests just the first world once i press the 'space' key , it does not sugggest anything further.

Answer (score 0):

ajax-solr is using facet to generate the dictionary of words that will be suggested. Facets will split results on each word by default.

You can have a complete 'title' suggester or phrase searcher if you copy each phrase to a multivalue list as it is mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/463047/not-getting-desired-results-from-solr-facets)

```
<copyField source="manufacturer" dest="manufacturerFacet"/>
```

This will copy the data you try to store at the manufacturer field to the manufacturerFacet automatically. This way you can set manufacturerFacet field as the following using string as base standard type with no tokenization.

```
<field name="manufacturerFacet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

so, what you have to do it's to copy each... title, manufacturer or category field (whatever the field you want to search as a phrase) in a multivalue field and then point to that list in your ajax-solr suggester.